# Opamp comparator output interfacing with digital circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator

I want to use Op amp as a comparator to shape the 50Hz sine wave to square wave, then route it to the PLL reference signal input, the PLL chip is 74HC4046. And i use AC coupled method. Because the supply of the Op amp is +/-15V, but the output signal amplitude need to be within +/-5V range. I have two solution to convert it:

1. Use diode to clamp the output to +/-0.7V or so.

[image]

2. Use transistor as below:

[image]

I want to know which one is better. Such as rising/falling time, delay, etc. I want the frequency is as stable as more.

Comment: Opamp as comparator is usually a bad idea.  @50Hz it shouldn't matter too much.  It mostly will depend on how the opamp behaves after driven to the rail, and not what's after it.  (You could use back to back 4.3V zeners in the first circuit. for ~+/-5V.)

Comment: If +/-0.7V is enough for me, 1N4148 should be OK, right?

Comment: Sure, the 10k ohm limits the current to about 1mA.

Comment: How big could the sinewave be - from where is it derived?

Comment: Why can't you use different rails with the opamp? If you use a rail-to-rail opamp and set the supplies to +/-5V, you wouldn't need to futz with the output. Also, to avoid chatter, I recommend adding hysteresis.

Comment: The input signal range is +/-15V, and there is no -5V supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the datasheet, VIH, Voltage-input-high, varies with VCC, and it's 1.5 volts when the chip is powered with 2 volts.  This means your first strategy won't work.

If you have a rail-to-rail op amp, you might be able to power it between +Vcc and ground, depending on how close to ground the output of your particluar op amp can go.  Check VIL on the data sheet for your PLL to figure this out, as well as your op amp data sheet

I also suggest that you arrange for some hysteresis on the input, to guarantee nice clean transitions.  You should consider a comparator instead of an op-amp.

Comment: Comparator usually has bigger offset voltage than precision Opamps, i want to minimize the offset voltage, so i choose to use Opamp. And for 4046, use AC coupling, it can accept signal as low as 150mV.

Comment: @diverger, regardless, you should still use some hysteresis.

Comment: Yes, you are right, i will.

Answer (score 1):

If the 50Hz sinewave is from the secondary of a transformer it might have decent enough amplitude to use back-to-back diodes (voltage limiting) with a capacitor voltage dropper to current limit the signal to the diodes. This overcomes having to use an op-amp.

This can be used directly from the mains AC voltage but it wouldn't be isolated - this is why I recommend using the secondary of the transformer although, with appropriate precautions and safety measures, this can work directly from the AC.

Comment: The input signal maybe small, so i need shape the signal to a more clean square wave and expect the op amp can do this work.